# Can no longer lock my screen on Ubuntu 20.04 with vanilla GNOME, how to debug?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, lock-screen, gdm

**Background:** I am using `vanilla-gnome-desktop` on a Ubuntu 20.04 which was installed from scratch. What was not done from scratch was the user profile. It got ported from another machine.

Now for some reason I am unable to lock my screen anymore, i.e. get the lock screen to appear while remaining logged on.

Essentially the shell appears to crash. The symptom is that the screen won't be locked and I am returned to my desktop. Some windows and the desktop background will flicker briefly, but then all returns to the unlocked desktop.

On occasion I am seeing an actual crash dialog from Ubuntu, referring to a `SIGSIGV` in `_st_theme_node_ensure_background()`.

The `gnome-shell` version is `3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1`.

My guess is that some profile settings could be messed up. How can I:

1. debug this issue further
2. reset the relevant setting/s (and preferably nothing more)

... in order to be able to lock my screen again?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is going to help anyone or if anyone else will ever encounter the same issue - I've come to the conclusion that perhaps the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 was causal in all this - but here is how I managed to resolve it.

There were a number of indicators in the `syslog` that this is an issue with extensions:

```
gnome-shell[31361]: Usage of object.actor is deprecated for dtpSecondaryAggregateMenu#012get@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:287:29#012_init@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/$ash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js:1183:9#012_setPanelMenu@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js:571:41#012_init@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js:163:18#012_createPanel@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panelManager.js:331:17#012enable/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panelManager.js:87:42#012enable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panelManager.js:86:77#012_enable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/extension.js:94:18#012enable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/extension.js:62:5#012_callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:166:32#012_onEnabledExtensionsChanged/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:475:18#012_onEnabledExtensionsChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:474:11
gnome-shell[31361]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
```

The first line contains (abbreviated below):

```
@resource:///.../gnome-shell/extensions/$ash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js:1183:9
```

... which corresponds to the [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) GNOME shell extension. And indeed when I tried deactivating it, I was able to lock my screen again.

I then looked in my home folder as to whether I could find any cache items corresponding to this extension to purge them. However, I came up empty-handed.

I then noticed that the extension seems to live a sort of double-life. Initially it was shown as "normal" extension. When I checked whether there was a package of the name, the package `gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` came up and it turned out that it was installed.

I first attempted `apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` and deactivating plus reactivating the extension, but that alone did not help.

After that I ended up purging the package (`apt purge gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel`) and noticed it was still shown in GNOME as installed system extension. So I deactivated it, but there was no option to remove it (as is normally the case for non-system extensions). So I deactivated it.

After all that I reinstalled the package `gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` and activated the extension and lo and behold I am now able again to lock my screen.

So perhaps I wasn't too far off with my guess regarding remnants from before my upgrade.